# Чередование согласных "п"->"f"

Tags: этимология, индоевропеистика

Существуют ли, помимо представленных ниже, ещё какие-либо слова в русском/старославянским, подчиняющиеся закону Гримма в части чередование согласных "п"->"f" с другими индоевропейскими языками (английским/немецким):
Для английского:
**f**lame -> **п**ламя;
**f**rog -> **п**рыг;
**f**oot -> **п**од     ([*pṓds](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/p%E1%B9%93ds))
 
Для немецкого:
**F**ichte -> **п**ихта (*pik-);
Stu**f**e -> сту**п**енька (*stÁb-, *stÁbʰ-, *stemb-, *stembʰ-);
kau**f**en -> ку**п**ить ([*kʷreyh₂-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/k%CA%B7reyh%E2%82%82-))

Answer (score 1):

Первый-first пойдет?

Тут, правда, при анализе возникает сложность, связанная с возможностью обратного перехода.
Если в русском слово было заимствованно уже из германских после их спирантизации (а не досталось в наследство из И-Е праязыка), то оно могло вторично принять форму с П, поскольку Ф в славянских долгое время отсутствовал вовсе. Поэтому искать примеры лучше не в русском, а в греческом и латыни, как все и делают, собственно. Но это уже другой уровень.